# Themes in Android are mixing

Tags: android, user-interface, styles

I have an app and I define to themes "A" and "B" inside the themes a define a set of styles

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.A" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat">
</style>

<style name="btnMiniPlayer" parent="Theme.A">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/image1</item>
</style>
```

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.B" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat">
</style>

<style name="btnMiniPlayer" parent="Theme.B">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/image2</item>
</style>
```

So I have in my app a property in a button

```
style="@style/button"
```

Depends of the style I need to change the image, also I set in the manifest the theme but the app is mixing the styles so for now I set the "A" like the primary theme but the app show the images from theme "B".

Any idea???

Comment: you mean the button when some event occurs(like button pressed), you want to change style of button?

Comment: I mean when the app start I set in the manifest the theme, but I set the style for theme A but the app is selecting the style from theme B

Comment: If the styles have the same name, won't the second style just overwrite the first?

Comment: On what condition do you need the image to change?

Comment: The user have an option in the app for select the theme, so I change the style in runtime, but the app for default start with theme A, but always show the image from theme B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to answer my question, so you need to follow the next steps in order to fix it

1- Create an attribute in my case I set the name like myButton:

```
<declare-styleable name="def_Styles">
    <attr name="myButton" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

2- In every Theme ("A" and "B") you have to define the item

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.B" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat">
    <item name="myButton">@style/CustomButtonB</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomButtonB" parent="Theme.B">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/image2</item>
</style>
```

3- In the view just set the style to the correct attribute

```
style="?myButton"
```

If you change the theme in the manifest between A and B it will be work

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<style name="button" parent="A">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/image</item>
</style>
```

drawable/image.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/image2" />
</selector>
```

There are also things like:

```
android:state_selected="true"
```

Comment: Yes I have to parents <resources>
    <style name="Theme.A" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat">
    </style>

    <style name="btnMiniPlayer" parent="Theme.A">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/image1</item>
    </style>
</resources>    

<resources>
    <style name="Theme.B" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat">
    </style>

    <style name="btnMiniPlayer" parent="Theme.B">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/image2</item>
    </style>
</resources>